# Running Java Security Manager without the default java.policy file

Tags: java, security, securitymanager

I don't want to modify anything in my java home directory, however, I am afraid that sometimes my default java.policy file may be too permissive. Is there a way for me to use a specified policy file as the only policy file when I run java with the `-Djava.security.manager` option?

If I add a `-Djava.security.policy=myPolicy.policy` option, it uses my policy file in addition to the default policy file -- which is bad because it looks like all permissions granted in the default policy file is still granted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[A Common Mistake with Java SecurityManager](http://javahowto.blogspot.fi/2006/05/common-mistake-with-java.html):

- To run with SecurityManager and default Java security policy, which
  is $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy:

  `java -Djava.security.manager Main`
- **To run with SecurityManager and
  only your custom security policy (ignoring default java security
  policy):**

  `java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==security.policy Main`
- To run with SecurityManager and default java security policy
  first, then your custom security policy:

  `java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=security.policy Main`
- If you don't want a SecurityManager, then simply leave out
  java.security.policy to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Wow... I would have not expect that to work, so counter intuitive to use == as an enforcer.

Comment: @TacB0sS I'm sure the Sun author who made this change didn't send it for code review :-D